# How do I use savon nested attributes! hash?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I'm looking at using Ruby savon for SOAP. For purely masochistic reasons I have to deal with SOAP elements having attributes.

So, no problem, there is an example on the savon docs site which highlights this ability:

```
{ :person => "Eve", :attributes! => { :person => { :id => 666 } } }.to_soap_xml
"<person id=\"666\">Eve</person>"
```

My problem is how do I set attributes on child elements, for example, say I add an address child element to person:

```
{ :person => {:address => ""}, :attributes! => { :person => { :id => 666 } } }.to_soap_xml
```

Now I want to add an id attribute to the address element:

It's no go if I nest address in the attributes hash:

```
{ :person => {:address => ""}, :attributes! => { :person => { :id => 666, :address => {:id => 44 }} }}.to_soap_xml
```

So my question is, how can I get this?

```
<person id=666><address id=44></address></person>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were close - just needed to put the `:attributes!` key in the same hash that contains the value.

```
{
  :person => {
    :address => "", 
    :attributes! => { :address => { :id => 44 } }
  }, 
  :attributes! => { :person => { :id => 666 } } 
}.to_soap_xml

# => "<person id=\"666\"><address id=\"44\"></address></person>"
```

Answer (score 18):

I ran across the issue of the previous answer no longer working. Eventually I found https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/518 which lead me to the correct syntax to add attributes now.

So the previous example would now be done as

```
{ 
  :person => {
    :@id => 666,
    :address => {
      :@id => 44
    }
  }
}
```

Which would generate the following xml

```
<person id="666">
  <address id="44"/>
</person>
```

Comment: how can I use it for this block .. <Shipments>
        <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">40665905851</string>
      </Shipments>

Comment: In case some poor soul comes looking for information on Savon XML attribute generation: `address: {'content!': "Downing street", '@id': 44}` would generate `<address id="44">Downing Street</address>`