# How do I add an attribute to a header tag with Savon?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

The header in my SOAP doc needs to have an attribute like this:

```
<soap:Header>
<eWAYHeader xmlns="https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/managedpayment">
  <eWAYCustomerID>string</eWAYCustomerID>
  <Username>string</Username>
  <Password>string</Password>
</eWAYHeader>
```

The eWAYHeader needs an xmlns attribute.

I've tried

```
    def create_customer(customer, card)
    response = @client.request(:create_customer, "xmlns" => "https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/managedpayment") do
      soap.header = header
      soap.body = create_customer_body(customer, card)
    end
  end

  private

  def header
    {
      "eWAYHeader" => {
        :attributes! => { :xmlns => 'http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/managedpayment' },
        "eWayCustomerID" => '87654321',
        "Username" => 'test@eway.com.au',
        "Password"=> 'test123'
      }
    }
  end
```

but the attributes! entry is ignored.

soap.header will only accept a Hash as an argument so I can't just set it's value using a string.

How do I achieve this in Savon?

thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve by doing this

```
soap.header = {
  "eWAYHeader" => {
    "eWayCustomerID" => '87654321',
    "Username" => 'test@eway.com.au',
    "Password"=> 'test123'
  },
  :attributes! => {"eWAYHeader" => { :xmlns => 'http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/managedpayment' } }, }
```

Comment: Thanks Anil, I finally got around to trying that and it did the trick.

Comment: The format has been updated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462391/850782