# SAVON don't put attributes to soap.body

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I try to send soap request. I use wsdl: http://soap.direct.yandex.ru/wsdl/v4/. But savon don't put attributes based on wsdl to request.
When I use php SoapClient, attributes inserted automatically into request

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlurl,
    array(
        'trace'=> 1,
        'exceptions' => 0,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'local_cert' => $local_cert,
        'passphrase' => ''
    )
);  
$params = array('param1','param2');
$result = $client->GetCampaignsList($params);
```

But in ruby Savon library attributes didn't insert into request

```
Savon.configure do |config|
    config.log = true            # disable logging
    config.log_level = :info      # changing the log level
    config.logger = Rails.logger  # using the Rails logger
end

client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl, http|
    wsdl.document  = "http://soap.direct.yandex.ru/wsdl/v4/"
    http.auth.ssl.cert_key_file = path_to_key_pem_file
    http.auth.ssl.cert_file = path_to_cert_pem_file
    http.auth.ssl.ca_cert_file = path_to_ca_cert_file
    http.auth.ssl.verify_mode=:none     
end

response = client.request :ns1, :get_campaigns_list do
    soap.body = { :params => ['param1', 'param2'] }
end
```

PHP request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="API" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetCampaignsList>
      <params SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString">
        <item xsi:type="xsd:string">name</item>
      </params>
    </ns1:GetCampaignsList>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Ruby request:

```
<?хml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xmlns:wsdl="API" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
              xmlns:ins0="API">
  <env:Body>
    <wsdl:GetCampaignsList>
      <params>
        <item>name</item>
      </params>
    </wsdl:GetCampaignsList>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Roman, can you post request that is made by php code and request made by ruby and specify more explicitly what 'attributes' are you missing in the latter one?

Comment: Alex, i added requests to question

Comment: missing attributes:  xsi:type="ns1:ArrayOfString"

Comment: SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]

Comment: I know this is an older question, but I found a working answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462391/850782

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
:attributes! => {"params" => {:'SOAP-ENC:arrayType' => 'xsd:string[1]'}}
```

It will add attribute to your params.