# How do you add nested attributes in Savon 2.3?

Tags: savon

Savon 2.1 used :attributes! to add attributes in nested xml tags. How is it done in 2.3? The exact same hash does not render the same xml.

```
{
  :person => {
    :address => "",
    :attributes! => { :address => { :id => 44 } }
  },
  :attributes! => { :person => { :id => 666 } }
}
```

creates

```
 <person>
    <address id="44"/>
  </person>
  <attributes>
    <person>
      <id>666</id>
    </person>
  </attributes>
```

instead of

```
<person id=\"666\"><address id=\"44\"></address></person>
```

For reference:
[How do I use savon nested attributes! hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394620/how-do-i-use-savon-nested-attributes-hash)

Another example where even the inner attributes! fails

```
{
  'Objects' => [{
    'EmailAddress' => 'CreatedUser@test.com',
    :attributes! => {
      'EmailAddress' => { 'xsi:type' => "tns:email" }
    }
  }],
  :attributes! => {
    'Objects' => { 'xsi:type' => "tns:Subscriber" },
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
  <Objects>
    <EmailAddress>CreatedUser@test.com</EmailAddress>
    <attributes>
      <EmailAddress>
        <xsi:type>tns:email</xsi:type>
      </EmailAddress>
    </attributes>
  </Objects>
  <attributes>
    <Objects>
      <xsi:type>tns:Subscriber</xsi:type>
    </Objects>
  </attributes>
```

Later example and ultimate reasoning for issue is attempting to create a subscriber for ExactTarget.

https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

```
 61 def soap
 62   @soap_client ||= Savon.client(
 63     soap_header:  header,
 64     wsdl:           'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
 65     endpoint:     endpoint,
 66     wsse_auth:    ["*", "*"],
 67     raise_errors: false,
 68     log:          true,
 69     open_timeout: 180,
 70     read_timeout: 180,
 71     pretty_print_xml: true
 72   )
 73 end

 112 def create_subscriber
 113   soap.call :create, :message => {
 114     'Objects' => [{
 115       'EmailAddress' => 'CreatedUser@test.com'
 116     }],
 117     :attributes! => {
 118       'Objects' => { 'xsi:type' => "tns:Subscriber" },
 119     }
 120   }
 121 end
```

Header omitted since it contains credentials.

Comment: My expectation is that this should still work in Savon 2.3. Trying to track down a WSDL that has some params I can pass to an operation to debug this is a little difficult.

Comment: ExactTarget wsdl is where I am having my errors. I'm trying to create a subscriber.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up getting like so:

```
   soap.call :create, :message => {
     'Objects' => [{
       'EmailAddress' => 'CreatedUser@test.com',
       :'@xsi:type'   => "tns:Subscriber"
     }]
   }
```

Attributes are flagged in the same level by using @